# what LINQ query will return results based on partial matches against arbitrary number of an entity's fields?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

consider the following code, which represents an attempt to implement partial matching. the intended result is a row for any 1 or more fields that match between the query entity and the data store.

so if you supply person.email we want a match against that, if you supply person.email and person.FirstName we should filter the results further, and so on.

```
        var results = from p in db.Persons
                      where p.CrookBookUserName.Trim().Contains(person.CrookBookUserName.Trim()) ||
                      p.email.Trim().Contains(person.email.Trim()) ||
                      p.FirstName.Trim().Contains(person.FirstName.Trim()) ||
                      p.LastName.Trim().Contains(person.LastName.Trim()) ||
                      p.phone.Trim().Contains(person.phone.Trim())
                      select p;

        return results;
```

unfortunately, this code always returns all rows in the db. why, and what should be the fix?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Note on variable naming: You're not returning any results, you're returning a query object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does person have all fields populated?  A `p.email.Trim().Contains("")` from an empty email address will return true for everything.

An extra `(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(..)) &&` before each parameter, while verbose, will fix it if this is the problem.

**Edit** re comments:

Yeah, a helper method or something could help here... something like

```
public static bool ContainsIfNotEmptyTrimmed(this string source, string param)
{
    return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(param.Trim()) && source.Trim().Contains(param.Trim());
}

where p.CrookBookUserName.ContainsIfNotEmptyTrimmed(person.CrookBookUserName) || ...
```

Comment: a thousand thanks, this pointed the way to working code: i want the user to be able to supply as many of the fields as they know, AND a partial string of any number of those. it's verbose but i don't care. 

having said that, can a lamda expression fix the verbosity?

Comment: this is the fixed code:

var results = from p in db.Persons
where ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(person.CrookBookUserName)) && p.CrookBookUserName.Trim().Contains(person.CrookBookUserName.Trim())) ||((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(person.email)) && p.email.Trim().Contains(person.email.Trim())) 
||((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(person.FirstName)) && p.FirstName.Trim().Contains(person.FirstName.Trim())) 
||((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(person.LastName)) && p.LastName.Trim().Contains(person.LastName.Trim())) 
|| ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(person.phone)) && p.phone.Trim().Contains(person.phone.Trim()))
select p;
return results;

Comment: @user283989: Editted with a simple extension method.  It's not really doing null checking correctly, but I'm sure you can figure that part out without much trouble if it's a problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the user is providing empty strings.

```
var query = db.Persons;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(person.CrookBookUserName.Trim()) {
    query = query.Where(p => p.CrookBookUserName.Trim().Contains(person.CrookBookUserName.Trim()));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(person.email.Trim()) {
    query = query.Where(p => p.email.Trim().Contains(person.email.Trim()));
}
// etc...

return query;
```

Comment: thanks for this: your reply reminds me that you can concatenate clauses in a query in this manner.